# How to avoid covering nodes with connection lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When drawing connection lines (`edge`) between nodes, the lines will be drawn over the nodes (due to the drawing sequence). If having many connections, it may problematically cover the nodes, and particularly the text therein. A very basic example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm] (first) at (1,1) {First};
   \node[fill=green,circle,text width=3cm] (second) at (5,5) {This is the text that will be cover with the connection lines};
   \node[fill=purple,circle,text width=3cm] (third) at (1,9) {This text will be covered too};

\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.east) to [out=0,in=0] (third.east);
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.west) to [out=180,in=75] (third.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Ideal Solution:** Turning the connection lines around the node. In fact, the node area should be a forbidden zone for lines.

**Practical Solution:** Passing the lines under the nodes. At least lines will not affect readability of the text.

How to implement one of these solutions to avoid lines over nodes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One solution (that could be put in the **practical** branch) is to use the `backgrounds` library.

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm] (first) at (1,1) {First};
\node[fill=green,circle,text width=3cm] (second) at (5,5) {This is the text that will be cover with the connection lines};
\node[fill=purple,circle,text width=3cm] (third) at (1,9) {This text will be covered too};
% insert connection lines in background 
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.east) to [out=0,in=0] (third.east);
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.west) to [out=180,in=75] (third.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The graphical result:

[image]

For details, see section 25 Background Library and section 82 Layered Graphics on the pgfmanual (version October 25, 2010).

> **EDIT**

Following Andrew Stacey's suggestion, in the code there will be defined a new layer set before the `main` layer (to see it in background with respect to the `main` layer).

The modified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}
\pgfsetlayers{background,myback,main} 
% to still have the possibility of exploiting the background layer
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm] (first) at (1,1) {First};
\node[fill=green,circle,text width=3cm] (second) at (5,5) {This is the text that will be cover with the connection lines};
\node[fill=purple,circle,text width=3cm] (third) at (1,9) {This text will be covered too};
% insert connection lines in background using myback layer
\begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.east) to [out=0,in=0] (third.east);
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.west) to [out=180,in=75] (third.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

will lead to the same graphical result shown above.

Comment: very tricky and simple approach!

Comment: This would conflict with using the `backgrounds` library for what it was designed for - putting a background behind the whole picture.  The same idea, but without this conflict, would be to declare a new layer for this purpose: `\pgfdeclarelayer{back}\pgfsetlayers{back,main}` then `\begin{pgfonlayer}{back}` instead of `background`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: A while ago you mentioned a sneaky badge... I think this one calls for it! `:)`

Comment: Not tricky but very natural approach ! There are a lot of examples in the pgfmanual that use the predefined background and Andrew's remark is very important. Now if you want to add a background rectangle with for example  `[background rectangle/.style=
     {draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=1ex},
   show background rectangle]`, you need to declare `\pgfsetlayers{background,myback,main} ` because  `background` is not in the new list.

Answer (score 4):

**Disclaimer:** This is an overkill for this case. Please read the comments.

Another option would be to use `append after command` key to use the node name and location before it's drawn in the picture. Since the `(second)` node is not related to the `(first)` and `(third)` interaction it can be placed later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=blue,circle,text width=3cm] (first) at (1,1) {First};
\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] node[
     fill=purple,
     circle,
     text width=3cm,
     append after command={
           (first.west) to [out=180,in=75] (third.north east)
     }]
     (third) at (1,9) {This text will be covered too};

\draw[->,thick,draw=red!50] (first.east) to [out=0,in=0] (third.east);

\node[fill=green,circle,text width=3cm] (second) at (5,5) {This is the text that will be cover with the connection lines};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The point here being that when a path is rendered, the path itself is drawn before the nodes so having them in the same command means that the nodes are drawn on top of the path.

Comment: @AndrewStacey That's a better way of putting it. But still to able to draw the path before the node shape we need to know where the node is located and where its shape border lies. Obviously you don't need no intro but the interested can check the manual Section 75.2.3 for more info.

Comment: Actually, in this case you don't need the `append after command` because you can just ... append it after the command.  That is, you can write `(first.west) to[out=180,in=75] (third.north east)` after the `(third)` node is defined and the path will be drawn under the node.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Bah, silly me. You are right.

Comment: The specifics may be overkill, but the general principle is not: that as nodes are rendered after the main path, it is possible to use the node positions *before* they are placed to draw something underneath them.  So just edit the answer to remove the unnecessary `append after path` and I think it's a fine answer.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Actually I think this is a fine nuance since you would not expect the behavior as it is. I would for example expect the other way around if I follow literally the command order. So maybe it might be beneficial for others.