# Placing a node on top of lines in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm using TikZ to draw a polytope/simplicial complex and I'd like to label the vertices with their names (which are numbers). However, in the picture below, the node seems to be placed behind the polytope, which looks ugly.

[image: Picture of portion of a polytope]

Is there a way to place the nodes on top of the polytope? Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel,x = {(.5cm,-0.7cm)}, y={(0.6cm,0.4cm)}, z={(-0.0cm,1.5cm)},scale=2]
\coordinate (G) at (0,0,1.5);   % 6
%% ...more coordinates 

\definecolor{cof}{RGB}{219,144,71}
\definecolor{pur}{RGB}{186,146,162}
\definecolor{greeo}{RGB}{91,173,69}
\definecolor{greet}{RGB}{52,111,72}

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) --(E) -- (F)-- cycle;
\draw (A) --(G);
\draw (G) --(I); %%
% ...more of the same

\tikzstyle{every node} = [circle, shade,ball color=green,inner sep=0pt,
  text width=8pt,font=\tiny,align=center, fill=cyan!20]
\node at (G) {\color{white}6};
 % ...more nodes

\draw[fill=pur,opacity=0.4] (A) -- (B) -- (G);
... more fillings
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can either postpone the `node` definition after the paths, or to use the `backgrounds` library and put on the `background layer` the paths (see the pgfmanual). One remark: `\color{white}` inside the text is completely useless. You can simply say: `\node[text=white] at (G){6}`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino: Thanks! I moved the nodes to the beginning of the documents and changed the \draw's to \path. You should post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino It's not completely useless just redundant. It makes the text white too.

Comment: @percusse: oh, that's just a personal campaign against the insertion of "things" inside the text rather than using the proper keys (with "things" I mean: text color and font specifications).

Comment: @cmhughes: I propose to close this as dup of [How to avoid covering nodes with connection lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58480/13304): it covers exactly the same topic. :)