# How to put one circle over another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.2);
\coordinate (C) at (3,2);
\coordinate (D) at (3,1.2);
\draw[fill=white] (A) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black] (B) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (C) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (D) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I use `pattern=north east lines` I can see first circle through second with pattern.

If I do not use `pattern=north east lines` I get what I want to see: second circle overlay first one.

But I need Second circle to be with pattern.

How this problem could be solved without using `\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}`?

Comment: I think [How to avoid covering nodes with connection lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58480/13304) can give you the correct way to proceed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `postaction` and draw the patterns after filling.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.2);
\coordinate (C) at (3,2);
\coordinate (D) at (3,1.2);
\draw[fill=white] (A) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white,
         postaction = {pattern=north east lines,pattern color=black}] (B) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (C) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (D) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In **Graphic Parameters: Fill Pattern** section from `TiKZ` documentation you can read

> ```
> Instead of filling a path with a single solid color, it is also possible to fill it with a tiling pattern.
> ```

Although it's not clearly stated, it looks like any `pattern` option replaces any previous `fill` option. Of course, any `fill` option will replace any `pattern` one. Just put `fill=white` after `pattern` in your code and see what happens.

Therefore, if you want a filled (non transparent) pattern, you need to draw it after (`postaction`) filling while node is drawn as it's shown in Harish's answer.

Another option is filling before (`preaction`) drawing the node and its filling pattern.

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]
\coordinate (A) at (2,2);
\coordinate (B) at (2,1.2);
\coordinate (C) at (3,2);
\coordinate (D) at (3,1.2);
\draw[fill=white] (2,2) circle (0.5);
\draw[preaction={fill=white},
         pattern=north east lines,pattern color=black] (B) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (C) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=white] (D) circle (0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```