# Reproducing diagrams in Tikz or similar packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

How to reproduce any of the following diagrams in Latex using TikZ or other packages
[image]

Especially I'm interested in seeing how the grid inside the circle to be done and the arrows such that the grid doesn't intersect them. Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates what you have tried so far ;)
Your question will very likely receive more attention when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Look for questions on this site that use `tikz` and `patterns` like this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169075/how-to-put-one-circle-over-another

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of diagrams these are? Do they have a name?

Comment: @AlanMunn These are generic diagrams of spin configuration in hydrogen atom. I found them in Feynman Lectures Vol. 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one of many ways to do this. In order to add a white halo around the spins, one can use the `preaction` key with which one draws a thicker, white version of the arrow beforehand. Other than that the patter can be conveniently done with the `patterns.meta` library. (If you have an older installation in which the library is not yet present, you can use `patterns` along with `north east lines`, which is harder to customize.) The sub diagrams can be put in a matrix.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{braket}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Triangle[length=2mm,width=1mm,round]},
    spin up/.style={preaction={draw,white,line width=2pt,
        -{Triangle[length=4mm,width=1.7mm,round]},shorten >=-1.6pt},
        black,->,shorten >=0pt},
    spin down/.style={preaction={draw,white,line width=2pt,
        {Triangle[length=4mm,width=1.7mm,round]}-,shorten <=-1.6pt},
        black,<-,shorten <=0pt},
    font=\sffamily,
    atom/.style={circle,minimum size=2cm,
    pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={4.5pt}]},
    label={[anchor=center,circle,fill,inner sep=0.6ex,alias=core]center:}
    }]
 \matrix[column sep=1em,row sep=1em]{   
 \node[atom,label=left:{$\ket{++},\ket{1}$}]{}; 
 \draw[spin up] (-0.3,-0.2) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \draw[spin up] (0,0.3) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \draw[<-] (0.3,0.7) -- ++ (45:0.5) node[above right]{electron};
 \draw[<-] (core) -- ++ (-20:1.2) node[right]{proton};
 &
 \node[atom,label=left:{$\ket{-+},\ket{3}$}]{}; 
 \draw[spin up] (-0.3,-0.2) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \draw[spin down] (0,0.3) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \\
 \node[atom,label=left:{$\ket{+-},\ket{2}$}]{}; 
 \draw[spin up] (-0.3,-0.2) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \draw[spin down] (0,0.3) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 &
 \node[atom,label=left:{$\ket{--},\ket{4}$}]{}; 
 \draw[spin down] (-0.3,-0.2) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \draw[spin down] (0,0.3) -- ++ (0,0.4);
 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]